# Samsung S3 GT-I9300 stuck on Download Mode, Failed in Odin

Tags: unbricking

Ive been trying to fix my Samsung S3 GT- I9300, stuck on Samsung Logo, Cant go to recovery mode anymore, can only go to download mode, and flashing thru Odin with stock firmware using only the PDA/AP

```
I9300XXUGNA5_I9300OLBGNB1_I9300DXUGNB1_HOME.tar
```

but gives me this error:

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> I9300XXUGNA5_I9300OLBGNB1_I9300DXUGNB1_HOME.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Odin engine v(ID:3.1005)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/003> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/003> sboot.bin
<ID:0/003> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/003> FAIL!
<ID:0/003> 
<ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Help!, i dont know what to do next.

Comment: Try flashing a different package to determine whether the problem is with the phone or the package.

Comment: i tried flashing a different one, but still giving me the same error

Comment: Did you solve the problem? How? Im have the same problem now :(

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. to give an update, eventually I was advised by a techncician that my motherboard already needs replacement. So I just bought another motherboard and had it replaced. @ruineves